# MySQL data insertion to a newly added column

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, database

I am new to MySQL. I have created a table and created 2 columns and inserted some elements. I created another column in same table. When I try to insert data in the new Column, it shows error like: `Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

I have tried the following:

```
for i in cur:
    print(i)
    age = int(input("age for "+i[0]))
    query = 'INSERT INTO student (student_name,age) values (%s,%d);'
    val = (i[0],age)
    cur.execute(query,val)
    con.commit()


student_name was already in the table.

query = 'INSERT INTO student (student_name,age) values ({0},{1}) on duplicate key update student_name = {0}, age = {1};'.format(i[0], age)
```

Both show same error. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Can you show the definition of your table? The create table statement? if you don't know how to get it run in whatever mysql client you have `show create table student;`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `student` (
   `student_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `student_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `student_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
   `age` int DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Comment: SOLVED: updated table using the primary key .. ive made some more changes in the command.query = "UPDATE student SET age = %s WHERE student_id = %s;"
    val = (age,id)             student_is is the primary key